# USB flash drive no longer being read by Xubuntu

Tags: files, xubuntu

This morning I used the flash drive but when I come back home to use it it no longer works. I'm starting to think that I might have corrupted it when I didn't eject properly. I ran fdisk to find the partition...

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I've found the device that looks like mine...

```
Disk /dev/sda: 15.6 GB, 15571353600 bytes
194 heads, 21 sectors/track, 7465 cylinders, total 30412800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa9f375df

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2880    30412799    15204960    b  W95 FAT32
```

What should I do from here to attempt to make the flash drive readable again?

---

EDIT:

As requested:

```
$ mkdir /media/nax/usb
$ mount /dev/sda1 /media/nax/usb
mount: can't find /dev/sda1/media/nax/usb in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

Comment: Add the output of `mount` to your answer, maybe the USB is just not mounted.

Comment: Log in again, anonymous edits of your own posts cause unneeded reviewing tasks.

Comment: @Nax you are running the command wrong, you need a space between `/dev/sda1` and `/media/nax/usb`, this is the reason you are getting an error. Also editing the question from another user is not ideal. Why not login to the same account you asked the question from.

Comment: What kind of computer are you using, and how old is it? This has happened to me once, with my 2004 Toshiba Satellite A105, and the problem was that my USB drives were busted. Could this be happening in your case?

Comment: I ended up fixing it, thanks for your help though guys!

Comment: Hi, how did you fixed it, got same issue! please post an answer!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mount your usb onto a folder to read it again.

```
mkdir /media/<your username>/usb
mount /dev/sda1 /media/<your username>/usb
```